# Python - passing arguments via browser (HTTP GET)

Tags: python, http, arguments

I am trying to pass an argument to a python script via HTTP

e.g. http://www.domain.com/script.py?param=value

in some examples, I can see people using the cgi.FieldStorage() function to retrieve the GET parameters, but I cannot make it work

this is my code:

```
import cgi

print "Content-type: text/html\n"
arguments = cgi.FieldStorage()
print arguments
```

by making the http request either by the browser or via commandline with wget, this is the output I get for the object `arguments`:

```
FieldStorage(None, None, [])
```

which doesn't seem to store the GET parameter

what am I missing?

Comment: try with http://docs.python.org/2/library/cgitb.html

Comment: Change your print statement so that its correct: `print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n"` - and then check it again.

Comment: it still doesn't work

Comment: Instead of CGI which is ancient, basic, and slow, consider using something lightweight but higher-level, like [web.py](http://webpy.org/) or [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/).

Answer (score 1):

in this way, it works!

```
import os, cgi

print "Content-Type: text/html\n"

query = os.environ.get('QUERY_STRING')
arguments = cgi.parse_qs(query) if query else {}
print arguments
```